# Finding correct FTM template for Digital Images (Online Commercial Site) for 1930 US census?

Tags: census-records, sources, 1930s

Looking at the source templates available to create a source for 1930 US Census using an online commercial site, FTM 3.1 (build 3.1 22.2.6) allows me to chose this option.

I am choosing the template "Census" with pull down options of "Digital Images" and "Population Schedules, United States 1880-1940 (by census year and location). It offers me the model to document information from a microfilm copy of population schedules for census years 1880 to 1940.

Is this the correct template for creating a source for an online commercial site?